# Change the color of mesh created using face3

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I have created a mesh using face 3 and three js. But the desired colour is not reflecting on the mesh. Here is the code used by me.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var f = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.real.length; i++, f += 4) {
    var o2 = i == data.real.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
    var tl = data.real[i];
    var tr = data.real[o2];
    var bl = data.zeroAxis[i];
    var br = data.zeroAxis[o2];

    geometry.vertices.push(tl, tr, br, bl);
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(f, f + 1, f + 2));
    face.materials = [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) ];

    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(f, f + 3, f + 2));
}
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color : new THREE.Color(0x008000),
    side : THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent : true,
    opacity : 0.5
});
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
this.plot = object;
this.tb.scene.add(object);
this.tb.render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, I resolved the above problem using the following code.

```
var normal = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0); // optional
    var color = new THREE.Color(color); // optional
    var materialIndex = 0; // optional
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(f, f + 1, f + 2, normal, color,
            materialIndex));
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(f, f + 2, f + 3, normal, color,
            materialIndex));
```

Please suggest the improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is not correct:

```
face.materials = [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) ];
```

If you want to apply a color per face, do it like that:

```
var faces = geometry.faces;

for ( var i = 0, l = faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var face = faces[ i ];
    face.color = new THREE.Color( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

}
```

Also set the property `vertexColors` of the corresponding material to `THREE.FaceColors`. Check out the following live demo so see a complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/8539/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide the face normals, you need to compute the normals. Look at [`Face3` docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Face3) top example:

```
//the face normals and vertex normals can be calculated automatically if not supplied above
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```