# Multiple materials on a single mesh doesn't update

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a mesh with different materials on different faces (so I can deconstruct and 'glitch' some loaded geometry).

For some reason I can't see any changes whatsoever, and I'm wondering if something has changed in three.js maybe. I'm sure this used to work but it's been a while, and now I get no errors but nothing updates.

I'm looking at this sort of example: https://dustinpfister.github.io/2018/05/14/threejs-mesh-material-index/

So something like:

```
function makeTestShape() {
  // An array of Materials
  var materialArray = [
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xff0000
      }),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0x00ff00
      }),
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: 0x0000ff
      })
  ];

  // Sphere
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 15, 15);

  // looping over all faces and setting the material index property
  geometry.faces.forEach(function (face, i) {
      face.materialIndex = Math.floor(i % materialArray.length);
  });

  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,materialArray);

  scene.add(sphere);
}
```

When I run this code, I get no visible geometry, but no errors either. Nothing happens. Is this still the correct way to do it? What am I missing? I've also tried every configuration of needsUpdate and this doesn't seem to do anything either...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put your scene renderer code too

Comment: I'm not doing anything else nonstandard, just an empty project gives the same result. So like: https://gist.github.com/danhett/bd9cbc9ca04e37f564d4b2a586339d99

Comment: (also worth noting, if I use a regular material on the same geometry everything works fine and renders correctly, it's just when I attempt multiple materials I get issues. not just with this example but others I've tried, leading me to wonder if something's changed?)

Comment: This problem is occurring because .setFaceCulling() method has been removed. You can use the texture instead.  var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal, color, materialIndex );
check out this.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.... can you put it into an answer with an example? then I can mark it correct too.  :)

Comment: Sure I will do, while the time you can view my similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172095/change-the-color-of-mesh-created-using-face3/51211300#51211300

Comment: Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/9394/